# Check REQUEST_URI for any /nl/ or /en/ to change my RewriteRules

Tags: php, .htaccess, content-management-system

I have my own CMS system with settings for an multi language website and I save this in my database. But I can't check that variable in my htacces so I want to check my request url like this:

cms2024.nl/nl/home or cms2024.nl/home and then give different RewriteRules to get my right url order

If there is an language in the url I want these rules:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /index.php?taal=$1&page=$2&title=$3&beginnenbij=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /index.php?taal=$1&page=$2&title=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /index.php?taal=$1&title=$2 [L]
```

and otherwise:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1&title=$2&beginnenbij=$3 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1&title=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?title=$1 [QSA,L]
```

how do I check this in my htaccess file for an right url build-up?

Comment: This is just my personal opinion, but my recommendation would be to take a page from other modern CMSs and handle all of this in PHP with a single router file. You’ll have access to the full PHP language instead of messing around with RegEx and faking query string parameters

Answer (score 0):

You only need one set of rules. (Providing you are OK to have an "empty" `taal` URL parameter when the language code is omitted - you should be.)

`([^/]*)` - Rather than check for *anything* in the first (language code) path segment, you need to be more specific and either check for the specific (2-char?) language codes you are expecting, eg. `(nl|en|id)`, or check for any lowercase 2-char path segment, eg. `([a-z]{2})`, providing that does not conflict with a `page`? And then make the first path segment *optional*.

For example, a single set of rules to handle both cases:

```
RewriteRule ^(?:([a-z]{2})/)?([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /index.php?taal=$1&page=$2&title=$3&beginnenbij=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^(?:([a-z]{2})/)?([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /index.php?taal=$1&page=$2&title=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^(?:([a-z]{2})/)?([^/]+)/$ /index.php?taal=$1&title=$2 [L]
```

Note that the first path segment (including the first slash) is made *optional* with the trailing `?` and this group in non-capturing (as denoted by the `(?:` prefix. However, the inner group that captures the language code *is* capturing. When the language code is omitted (ie. the first path segment is not lowercase 2-chars) then the `$1` backreference is simply *empty*, but is still present, so the following backreferences are not renumbered.

Note also that I changed the quantifier from `*` to `+` for subsequent path segments. It doesn't make much sense to use `*` here, which makes it "look-like" it allows an *empty* path-segment, eg. `/nl/foo//baz` - which would never be matched by the first rule anyway since the double slash in the middle is "resolved away" in the URL-path that the `RewriteRule` matches against so the URL would fall-through to the rule that follows anyway.